# Cannot specify `Not` operator in cost explorer filter

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to use the aws-sdk-js to query data from cost explorer. It was all working fine until I tried adding a `Not` to my filter, and encountered this error -

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: Not
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.get Not [as Not] (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cost-explorer-node/model/shapes/_Expression.ts:18:14)
    at JsonBuilder.format (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/@aws-sdk/json-builder/src/index.ts:62:57)
    at JsonBuilder.format (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/@aws-sdk/json-builder/src/index.ts:62:37)
    at JsonBuilder.build (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/@aws-sdk/json-builder/src/index.ts:36:32)
    at JsonRpcSerializer.serialize (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/@aws-sdk/protocol-json-rpc/src/JsonRpcSerializer.ts:29:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serializer/src/index.ts:24:39)
    at step (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at fulfilled (/Users/yaron/code/cloud-cost-fetcher/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:62)
```

The same filter works perfectly fine when I use the AWS CLI, so I'm suspecting this has something to do with the cost explorer client implementation.

Here's the relevant from my code that produce this error -

```
import { GetCostAndUsageCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-cost-explorer-node/commands/GetCostAndUsageCommand'
import { CostExplorerClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-cost-explorer-node/CostExplorerClient'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'


  const costExplorer = new CostExplorerClient({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: billingProfile }),
  })
  const getCostAndUsageCommand = new GetCostAndUsageCommand({
    TimePeriod,
    Granularity: 'MONTHLY',
    GroupBy: [
      {
        Type: 'TAG',
        Key: '<TAG_NAME>',
      },
    ],
    Filter: {
      Not: {
        Dimensions: {
          Key: 'LINKED_ACCOUNT',
          Values: ['<ACCOUNT_NUMBER'],
        },
      },
    },
    Metrics: [metricsType],
  })
```

I'm using the following aws npm modules -

```
"@aws-sdk/client-cost-explorer-node": "^0.1.0-preview.2",
"aws-sdk": "^2.747.0",
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the same [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1652) on the aws-sdk-js repository and got a quick and helpful answer from one of the maintainers. Seems like this module is deprecated and should be changed for another one, posting this answer here in case anyone in the future needs this piece of information.